# Apply recurring conditional check to all derived classes

Tags: c#, derived-class

I got a job base class with an abstract Work() method. This gets overridden/implemented in my inherited classes.

What I want to achieve is applying an abort condition to all derived classes. The template method pattern doesn't seem to help me here, because I need this check to occur in my abstract Work()-class.

A workaround would be making Work() virtual, but then I'm no longer forcing the implementation of it (what I want to do):

```
public abstract class First
{
    protected virtual void Work()
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}

public class Second : First
{
    protected override void Work()
    {
        base.Work();
    }
}
```

Is there any way to achieve my goal?

Comment: It's hard to tell what you want exactly, but how about a `public void Work()` in `First` which does the cancel check and calls `protected abstract void WorkInternal()` which is implemented in the derived classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The template method pattern doesn't seem to help me here, because I need this check to occur in my abstract `Work()`

You picked the right pattern, but you did not apply it properly.

The idea behind the template method pattern is to make `Work` non-virtual, and provide a separate method, virtual or abstract, for subclasses to override. This way all the checks that could abort a job would be performed in the `Work` function of the base class, while the derived classes would provide actual implementations for what to do when the checks have succeeded:

```
public abstract class First {
    public void Work() {
        if (!CheckPreconditions()) {
            // Abort the job
            return;
        }
        DoWork();
    }
    protected abstract void DoWork();
}

public class Second : First {
    protected override void DoWork() {
        // Do the actual work here
    }
}
```